# How to send email without enabling "Access for less secure apps"

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, gmail

In my mail configurations:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=lol
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

But my testing email was enabled for "access for less secure apps". Is there a chance to send email to any types of email? Currently, I can't get a server email and they configuration. I need to create my own email and integrate to the website.

My searches give me "2-step verification". Is system can automatically send emails If I enabled this? I can't get any solution. I hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would research using the google mail API.

Comment: @Joseph_J what did you find?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Log to your gmail account
2. My account > Sign In And Security > Sign In to google
3. Enable two step verification, then you can generate app password
4. You can use that app password in `.env` file.

`.env` will look like

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=pass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

If you got error `Expected response code 220 but got code` remember to clear cache after any changes in `.env` file:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Thanks sir. But i got this error. 
Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""
What did i do wrong?

Comment: I am working shared hosting. Also website is published. I can't use these commands. But i changed the "TLS" to "SSL" and it worked. But i don't have ssl. This looks like a problem. But that worked anyway.

Comment: Thank you @AdamKozlowski

Comment: You've helped the guy working with Golang!.... Thanks so much dude!